# Quick Regex for the sentences

Tags: c#, regex

I need help with the following regex in c#. I have a given string which I am trying to select text like this. The string is from an invoice. The remaining item will be the item purchased.

```
510258-350-JDX 84008043942000 Confirmation of Order is mandatory.994007029908500 ItemMaterial NumberDescription64008029908500Order 840780-16742500
Long text *** Text***  ==> 84008043942000 Confirmation of Order is mandatory.994007029908500
ItemMaterial NumberDescription64008029908500Order 840780-16742500


510258-350JDFT8 84008043942000 Confirmation of Order is mandatory.994007029908500ItemMaterial NumberDescription94008029908500Order 840080-16742500 Long text 232 *** Text***  ==> 84008043942000 Confirmation of Order is mandatory.994007029908500
ItemMaterial NumberDescription64008029908500Order 840080-16742500
```

but my current way is not working. I want to select these and remove them from the string. The numbers in the example can change.

```
string r2 = raa.Replace(r1, "");
string rgconfirm ="";
string rgorder ="";

if (r2.Contains( "Confirmation")) {
    rgconfirm = Regex.Match(r2, @"(\d{14} Confirmation)").Groups[0].Value;
    if (r2.Contains("-")) {
        rgorder = Regex.Match(r2, @"(Order \d{6}-*+\d{8})").Groups[0].Value;
    }
}

string check1 = rgconfirm + "(.*?)" + rgorder;
var toreplace = Regex.Match(r2, check1).Groups[0].Value;

if (toreplace.Length > 2) {
    r2 = r2.Replace(toreplace, "");
}
```

Comment: Please specify exactly the output you are looking for.

Comment: Note that Groups[0] is the entire match. Groups[1] is the first capture group. [Source:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) "the first element of the GroupCollection object (the element at index 0) returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern. Each subsequent element, from index one upward, represents a captured group"

Comment: Example inputs and outputs with expected outputs would be helpful.

Comment: the example is in the question. the output i want is after "==>" in the first code block

Comment: Do you want the number before "Confirmation of Order is mandatory" ?

Comment: yes I want the number before "Confirmation of Order is mandatory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the number before the text "Confirmation of Order is mandatory", you could use the following Regex:

```
(?<==>\s)\d+?\s*Confirmation of Order is mandatory.+?ItemMaterial NumberDescription\d+?Order\s\d+-?\d+
```

If your pattern always remain the same, the above regex expression should work.
Use the above regex pattern with `RegexOptions.Singleline` option.

Comment: i want the text like this : 84008043942000 Confirmation of Order is mandatory.994007029908500
ItemMaterial NumberDescription64008029908500Order 840780-16742500

Comment: Updated again. Also, take care to use `RegexOptions.Singleline` option.